# JSON - Conversion to VB.NET Object

Tags: json, vb.net, json-deserialization

I am new to JSON strings so I am having a hard time with it.
I am used to SOAP Web Services where in Visual Studio automatically creates the strongly typed Classes for me in the background.

JSON - REST Web Services are for me is much tedious as I have to create manually the equivalent Strongly Typed Classes. (Or I maybe wrong).

I have this JSON String being returned to me by a REST Web Service:

***{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"command":["Required property 'Vendor' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 310."],"command.Terms":["The Terms field is required."]}}***

Could you guide me on the equivalent Class?

Appreciate your help!

Regards,
Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using JSON.NET...

```
Public Class Response
    Public Property Message As String
    Public Property ModelState As ModelState
End Class

Public Class ModelState
    <JsonProperty("command")>
    Public Property Command As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    <JsonProperty("command.Terms")>
    Public Property Terms As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim response As Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString)
```

Comment: Thanks Sam! It DE serialized perfectly.